# air launch configuration opens external swf viewer (fdt)

Tags: sdk, launch, fdt

i have been using fdt for about a month now, working on a air desktop app. untill now, everything worked fine. but yesterday, i tried to create an other project, and nothing works anymore: when i try to launch the app, it launches the "external swf viewer" instead, with nothing in it.
I bet this comes from the launch/debug settings, but i don't remember changing the ones of the  older project.

I a little bit lost with the sdk's too... i found one that seemed to work, but i really don't know why. (when i try one downloaded from adobe's website, fdt tell me that it cant find any sdk in it) I could also come from that.

If you need more information please tell me.

Comment: Could you post some screenshots and or video? That would help tremendously.

Comment: here is a link to download screenshots, the console log and the folder created by fdt for a new air-desktop project(all in a .zip file): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107202206/fdt%20bug.zip

Comment: Everything looks fine. Nothing has been added to the display so the SWF will be blank. How about creating a simple circle on the screen e.g. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciu5p83c9m8deil/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-12%20at%202.26.12%20PM.png

Comment: the problem is that i created an air project, and fdt launches it on swf launcher...
do you want me to try to draw a circle anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. Try this: http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-3168
Worked for me!

Comment: Here's my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728647/fdt-launches-external-swf-viewer-instead-of-adl