# FDT launches external swf viewer instead of ADL

Tags: fdt

I have a newly downloaded copy of FDT5, with the Flex 4.6 SDK merged with AIR 3.7 SDK. When I launch a FDT AIR App project 'on desktop', it launches the "external swf viewer" instead of the ADL. I have spent the day googling and have no idea why it could be doing this. The app works fine on the iPhone itself. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Phew, I have found the solution (touch wood!) http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-3168

Comment: Post the answer to your own question!

Comment: Read the info on the link, it answers the question.

Comment: "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/